# Entity framework object context saves new entities that were not added

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, objectcontext

I have been working with Entity Framework (VS2010 Framework 4.0) in my proyect. I had some trouble with using a different object context per form. What I did then, was to create a object context in the Main Menu Form (stays opened) and everytime I create and show one form, I pass that object context to this new form. Example:

```
 public partial class frm_Menu : Base
{
    public Sistema_financiero_Entities db = new Sistema_financiero_Entities();

    private void cancelarCuotaToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm_Cancelacion_Cuota Form1 = new frm_Cancelacion_Cuota();
        Form1.db = db;
        Form1.Show();
    }
}
```

Ok, that solution worked fine until now because I needed to use and pass objects throw the differents forms sometimes, and if the objects contexts were different, I got an error.

Now, I have detected a huge issue using it this way. I have a form, where I can pay for the different installments of a loan. I´ll attach an image so then you can see what I´m talking about.

[image]

There, you select the different installments you want to pay for. Then, you introduce the value you will finally pay in "Total cobrado". Here is the important thing: When the checkbox image is checked (the blue one - already checked in the image), I create a "payment" entity per installment. Every "payment" object is stored in a list. If I uncheck it, I can change the value and the same thing is done. Obviously, I´m clearing the list before doing a `list.Clear();`. Then, one the checkbox checked, I can press "Aceptar" (accept). There I add to the database every "payment"(PAGO) in the list. After that, I save all changes.

```
foreach (Pago p in Lista_nuevos_pagos)
{
    db.AddToPago(p);
}
try
{
    db.SaveChanges();
    this.Close();
}
```

My problem, is that it´s not only adding those "payments" in the list but the other "payments" entities that were in the list before clearing it. I reach the conclusion that when I clear the list, the objects remains in the object context. I thought that if the entity is not in the database, I have to Add it to the entity in the object context as I did with pago (`db.AddToPago(p);`).

I wanted to ask you guys how can I solve this issues. I solved it now doing this:

```
private void cancelarCuotaToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Sistema_financiero_Entities db = new Sistema_financiero_Entities();
        frm_Cancelacion_Cuota Form1 = new frm_Cancelacion_Cuota();
        Form1.db = db;
        Form1.Show();
    }
```

Instead of creating just one global db for all forms, I create one in the Main Menu for every form. Then, in that form closed event, I dispose that object context. 
Then, when i check the checkbox image, before creating the "payments", I delete every "Pago" entity from the object context:

```
foreach (Pago p in Lista_nuevos_pagos)
        {
            db.DeleteObject(p);
        }

Lista_nuevos_pagos.Clear();
```

Doing this works correctly, but I´m still having trouble with some other created entities (Installments) that are not deleted when I clear a list. I think I´m doing it wrongly, thats why I need some direction to use EF correctly. I really need to get this done really soon, I don´t have too much time to read EF tutorials.

Just in case, this is how I create every "Pago" (payment)

```
Pago p = new Pago();                                                    
p.desc_aumento_intereses = nudwb1.Value;                            
p.desc_aumento_punitorios = nudwb2.Value; 
p.desc_aumento_gastos = nudwb3.Value;                           
p.desc_aumento_comision = nudwb4.Value;
p.cotizacion = ntxt_Cotizacion.Value;
p.fecha_hora = fecha_hora;

Cuota c = new Cuota();
string name = tbx.Name.Substring(tbx.Name.IndexOf("-") + 1);
int nro_cuota = Convert.ToInt32(name);
c = Lista_cuotas_cobrar.Where(x => x.num_cuota == nro_cuota).First();

p.Cuota.Add(c);
```

Thank you for reading, I know this is a lot of info. Hope some guide soon..

Comment: Wow!This is a nice form.What controls do you used for this table with column "Fecha de vencimineto"?

Comment: Thanks, actually its a DataGridView with custom paint events. I havent used any third party control.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you have references to those object in your Lista_nuevos_pagos list. This is why they will be duplicated.

Comment: I worked it out. Instead of doing the db.delete(p) I do detach. Every created entity object is attached to the context. Thats why it was still saving temporary objects.

Comment: There isn't a good way to remove entities tracked by the context aside from throwing away the context. Ideally you should not keep the same context instance around.